# How to cancel asynchronous callback function in C++/WRL?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, windows-10, windows-store, wrl

I'm writing Windows 10 Store / WinRT code using [C++/WRL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh438466.aspx) which I'm new to. And I'm curious to know how do I cancel long-pending asynchronous operation?

The best way to illustrate it is with this example:

```
#include <Windows.Services.Store.h>
#include <wrl.h>

auto onAppLicCompletedCallback = Callback<Implements<RuntimeClassFlags<ClassicCom>, IAsyncOperationCompletedHandler<StoreAppLicense*>, FtmBase>>(
    [](IAsyncOperation<StoreAppLicense*>* operation, AsyncStatus status)
{
    //Asynchronous operation is done
    return S_OK;
});

//'opAppLic' is defined as:
// ComPtr<IAsyncOperation<StoreAppLicense*>> opAppLic;
// ...

//Begin asynchronous operation
HRESULT hr = opAppLic->put_Completed(onAppLicCompletedCallback.Get());
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    //Keep going ...

    //Say, at some point here I need to cancel 'onAppLicCompletedCallback'
    //but how do I do it?
}
```

**EDIT:** When I tried to add `opAppLic->Cancel()` as was suggested in the answer below, it gave me the following compiler error:

```
1>file-name.cpp(597): error C2039: 'Cancel' : is not a member of 'Microsoft::WRL::Details::RemoveIUnknownBase<T>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=ABI::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<ABI::Windows::Services::Store::StoreAppLicense*>
1>          ]
```

Do I need to `QueryInterface` that `IAsyncInfo` instead, or what?

**EDIT2:** This is what I'm getting for the type of `opAppLic` variable:

[image]

And no, it doesn't have the `Cancel` method:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[`IAsyncOperation<TResult>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206598.aspx) has a [`Cancel()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.iasyncinfo.cancel.aspx) method inherited from [`IAsyncInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.iasyncinfo.aspx).

You cannot cancel the `Completed` handler itself. It is fired when the async operation is finished. You have to cancel the operation instead, and then the `Completed` handler reports the final status of the operation.

```
#include <Windows.Services.Store.h>
#include <wrl.h>

auto onAppLicCompletedCallback = Callback<Implements<RuntimeClassFlags<ClassicCom>, IAsyncOperationCompletedHandler<StoreAppLicense*>, FtmBase>>(
    [](IAsyncOperation<StoreAppLicense*>* operation, AsyncStatus status)
{
    //Asynchronous operation is done
    if (status == completed)
    {
        // use results from operation->GetResults() as needed...
    }
    return S_OK;
});

ComPtr<IAsyncOperation<StoreAppLicense*>> opAppLic;
// Begin asynchronous operation that assigns opAppLic...

opAppLic->put_Completed(onAppLicCompletedCallback.Get());

//Keep going ...

//Say, at some point here I need to cancel the operation...
opAppLic->Cancel();
```

Comment: Sorry. There's no `Cancel` method for `opAppLic`. I updated my original post with details.

Comment: @c00000fd The MSDN documentation I linked to in my answer states otherwise: "*`IAsyncOperation<TResult>` inherits `IAsyncInfo`. Types that implement `IAsyncOperation<TResult>` also implement the interface members of `IAsyncInfo`: **`Cancel` method**, `Close` method, `ErrorCode` property, `Id` property, `Status` property*" It seems the real culprit is the `RemoveIUnknown*` returned by `ComPtr::operator->()`. I don't know why, but try using `opAppLic.Get()->Cancel()` instead, since `Get()` doesn't use `RemoveIUnknown`.

Comment: Thanks. I see the documentation. I wish I knew more about this stuff to know why the `Cancel` method is not there. I updated my OP with more info.

Comment: Hey, any more ideas on this one?

Comment: @c00000fd: Sorry, I can't answer that.  I don't use WRL.

Comment: Well WRL is just a wrapper class for the native COM stuff, pretty much like MFC is for Win32, right? So wouldn't your `Get()` method expose the native interface pointer? And if so there must be something else to it, since it doesn't work there either. My guess is that they must have changed something in that `ABI` namespace. Anyway, appreciate your help!

Comment: @c00000fd: I don't know how WRL works, but just from glancing at it, it looks like much more than a simple wrapper, but a whole framework of its own.

Answer (score 1):

Whoever also runs into this. I think I got it. *Remy Lebeau* was partially correct. What I needed to do was to obtain `IAsyncInfo` via `QueryInterface` as such:

```
ComPtr<IAsyncInfo> pAsyncInfo;
if(SUCCEEDED(opAppLic->QueryInterface(__uuidof(pAsyncInfo), &pAsyncInfo)) &&
    pAsyncInfo)
{
    if(SUCCEEDED(pAsyncInfo->Cancel()))
    {
        //Async op was now canceled
        //Also note that `onAppLicCompletedCallback` will be called
        //with `status` set to `Canceled`
    }
}
```

Comment: `ComPtr` provides a simpler syntax for doing `QueryInterface()` by the `As()` method. eg. 
`ComPtr<ABI::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncInfo> pAsyncInfo;
opAppLic.As(&pAsyncInfo)`. 

For more information, see - https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr#obtaining-new-interfaces

Comment: _Adding to my previous comment_ - 
`ComPtr<ABI::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncInfo> pAsyncInfo;
opAppLic.As(&pAsyncInfo)` is equivalent to `opAppLic->QueryInterface(__uuidof(pAsyncInfo), &pAsyncInfo))`