# How to properly wait for asynchronous WinRT callback functions to stop?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-async, wrl

I [asked a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40201439/how-to-cancel-asynchronous-callback-function-in-c-wrl) before but the answer there did not satisfy my requirement. Let me explain.

I call the following code from a DLL to perform a WinRT operation on Windows 10 from a Windows Store app. The code uses [WRL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh438466.aspx):

```
#include <Windows.Services.Store.h>
#include <wrl.h>

auto onAppLicCompletedCallback = Callback<Implements<RuntimeClassFlags<ClassicCom>, IAsyncOperationCompletedHandler<StoreAppLicense*>, FtmBase>>(
    [](IAsyncOperation<StoreAppLicense*>* operation, AsyncStatus status)
{
    if(status == AsyncStatus::Completed)
    {
       //Do actions of the async operation
       ...
    }

    return S_OK;
});

//'opAppLic' is defined as:
// ComPtr<IAsyncOperation<StoreAppLicense*>> opAppLic;
// ...

//Begin asynchronous operation
HRESULT hr = opAppLic->put_Completed(onAppLicCompletedCallback.Get());
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    //Keep going ...

    //Say, at some point here I need to cancel 'onAppLicCompletedCallback'
    //after a user clicks Cancel button via a UI, so I do this:
    ComPtr<IAsyncInfo> pAsyncInfo;
    if(SUCCEEDED(opAppLic->QueryInterface(__uuidof(pAsyncInfo), &pAsyncInfo)) &&
        pAsyncInfo)
    {
        pAsyncInfo->Cancel();
    }
}

//And now unload DLL
```

but when I call the `IAsyncInfo::Cancel()` method and unload the DLL immediately after, that causes a race condition and sometimes crashes the app.

Purely experimentally I noticed that after a call to `IAsyncInfo::Cancel()` the framework calls my `onAppLicCompletedCallback` method with `status` set to `AsyncStatus::Canceled`. But this call also happens asynchronously long after `IAsyncInfo::Cancel()` method returns.

So I was wondering, is there a way to wait for all WinRT asynchronous callbacks to finish running before I can proceed with unloading my DLL?

Comment: I am trying to involve someone familiar with this topic to further look at this issue. There might be some time delay. Appreciate your patience.

Comment: @MattewWu-MSFT: I appreciate if you guys can straighten it out...